# A way to push array of objects into an array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is the array of objects that is to be push to an array

```
[{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}]
```

How to achieve this array below from the above

```
"array": [
[
  [
    11,
    21
  ],
  [
    31,
    41
  ],
  
  [
    10,
    20
  ],
  [     
    11,  //first object again
    21
  ]  
]
]
```

Used array map to push elements but couldn't figure out a way to push the first object again

```js
var array1 = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}];

var array2 = [array1.map(item=>[item.a, item.b])];

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add another line of code that inserts that first index.

```js
var array1 = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}];

var array2 = [array1.map(item=>[item.a, item.b])];
array2[0].push([array1[0].a, array1[0].b]);

console.log(array2);
```

Do you need the double array on the outside though?

Anyway, another way would be to just copy the first array you originally pushed.

```js
var array1 = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}];

var array2 = [array1.map(item=>[item.a, item.b])];
array2[0].push(array2[0][0].slice());

console.log(array2);
```

And you can also make your `.map()` a little different using `Object.values`:

```js
var array1 = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}];

var array2 = [array1.map(Object.values)];
array2[0].push(array2[0][0].slice());

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```js
var array1 = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}];
array1.push(array1[0])

var array2 = [array1.map(item=>[item.a, item.b])];

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done my manually pushing the first element again after you've done the mapping.

The `unshift()` method can be used to push to the front of array.

```
var array2 = [array1.map(item=>[item.a, item.b])];
array2.unshift([array1[0].a, array1[0].b])
```

Comment: You need to push to `array2[0]`

Comment: @slappy Edited, I meant to say `unshift`

Comment: You don't want `unshift` because he wants it at the end. But take a close look at the OP's result. He has `[[ [...], [...], [...] ]]`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with slappy's answer, but no need to apply slice

```js
const arr = [{"a":11,"b":21},{"a":31,"b":41},{"a":10,"b":20}];
const arr2 = [arr.map(item=>[item.a, item.b])];
arr2.push(arr2[0][0]);
```

Comment: If the items in `arr2` will be mutated in the future, then mutating the first item would also alter the last, because a copy is not made. If not, then a `.slice()` is unnecessary, but I'd probably still do it.